# Independent sets into which all the vertices of the graph can be split

Tags: algorithms, graphs, matching

How to prove that if $G$ is an acyclic transitive digraph, then the least independent sets into which all vertices of G can be divided is equal to the size of the longest paths to $G$?

Answer (score 1):

This is [Mirsky's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirsky%27s_theorem), a sort of dual of [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20in%20the%20areas,Dilworth%20(1950).). Dilworth's theorem is a standard result in the combinatorics of posets.

Comment: Can you explain how this theorem is related to my problem? I just can't understand how partially ordered sets and a graph are related.

Comment: Take it as a puzzle. In computer science, often two things that look very different at first, turn out to be the same if observed from the right angle.

Comment: With a little thought, I figured out how to connect another graph and a partially ordered set. The connection between independent sets and antichains also became apparent. But how to prove that there is a chain of length n (n is the number of elements of the antichain)?

Comment: You're right, you actually need the dual to Dilworth's theorem, which is easier to prove.

Comment: But if we use this theorem, how can we find the least number of antichains?

Comment: Okay, I think I figured it out. Thank!

Comment: I still don't fully understand which ordering relation we have to take in order to make a partially ordered set out of a graph. Can you tell me how to find it?

Comment: $x<y$ if there’s an edge from $x$ to $y$.